# include xib on multiple other interfaces using only Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a button that I've *customized* and I want to use it on *multiple* pages. Is there a way to do this by "linking" it to another `xib` if it's on it's own `xib`? That would make things a lot easier from the design standpoint (rather than building, checking pixel gaps, etc).

I'm know I can *accomplish* this with code, but I just want to know if this is possible using `Interfrace Builder` only and if it is - ***how***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIView *someXIBOrNIB = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"someXIBOrNIB" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
[self addSubView:someXIBOrNIB];
```